# AWS job to output CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Lambda setup to run a query against a MySQL RDS database (once a day) and return the results to a PowerBI instance in a comma separated format.  The data being returned is too large now and the Lambda is failing because of it.

To resolve this quickly, I setup a PowerAutomate script to run the query (via a Bastion host) and create a csv file that gets uploaded to a share that the PowerBI instance now intakes.

I want to find a way to do all this in the AWS environment that the RDS instance exists in.

I'm thinking that I can have the endpoint be an S3 bucket that is protected by IAM (the PowerBI instance would assume that IAM role to access the bucket).  However, I do not know how to actually run the query.  It would be something that just runs the query once a day and uploads the file so I'm guessing something that is triggered by a Cloudwatch event but I don't know what that thing is.

I don't have much experience setting up EC2 instances but I imagine that is where I'd have to go but is there a way to just wake up an EC2 instance for this one job and then terminate it right after so that I can keep costs low?  Any alternatives are welcome.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [ECS Scheduled tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/scheduled_tasks.html), which is backed by AWS ECS.

From my experience, once the job is running too long or consuming too much resources that Lambda can handle, I will turn to use ECS Scheduled tasks.

ECS Scheduled tasks requires more configuration, but it can be serverless like Lambda(by using [Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/what-is-fargate.html)) and it is easier to run and deploy than EC2. It also support ClouldWatch event triggers.

In short, major steps you need to do are:

- wrap your script into a docker image and push it to [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)
- create a [ECS Scheduled tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/scheduled_tasks.html) with cron expression
- give it an appropriate [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html)

It will work like a charm.

AWS tutorials like https://ecsworkshop.com/introduction/ecs_basics/task/ might help you. Enjoy ECS!